# APK static analysis tools - frameworks used, vulnerability checks, etc?

Tags: android, tools, static-analysis

I'm familiar with tools for unpacking/decompiling APKs - JADX, apktool, dex2jar, JD-GUI, and the like. I'm curious if there are tools which automate other useful tasks when reversing an APK, such as:

- Recognizing frameworks and SDKs built into the app
- Classifying the types of resources built into the app
- Scanning for common security blunders
- Finding all URLs, emails, etc.

I've come across [super](https://github.com/SUPERAndroidAnalyzer/super), though I haven't found it incredibly useful in my use cases.

Comment: https://github.com/ashishb/android-security-awesome

Comment: https://ghidra-sre.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can look at DeepDive for Android, https://github.com/Nuvolect/DeepDive-Android.
In addition to Jadx, it uses CFR and Fernflower. It indexes text artifacts with the Lucene search engine and has preconfigured search sets to find emails, passwords, analytics, and a few others. It runs on Android but you can use your laptop or other big screens via the embedded Nanohttpd web server and elFinder. The app is in beta.